# adding column though loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, dynamic-sql, alter-table

i created a table  #cinema

```
c_name c_count
   a      1
   b      2
   c      3
   d      4
```

and a table #display

```
name id
```

how can i add c_name to table #display as column through loop like:

```
name id a b c d
```

here's my code

```
select @ccount = COUNT(c_count) from #cinema

set @count = 0
while @count < @ccount
begin
    select @cname = c_name from #cinema
    set @txt = 'alter table #display add ' + @cname + ' money default 0 with values'
    exec(@txt)
    set @count = @count+1
end
```

help me pls. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @dsql nvarchar(max) = N''  
SELECT @dsql += 
  'ALTER TABLE #display ADD ' + QUOTENAME(c_name) 
+ ' money DEFAULT 0 WITH VALUES ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM #cinema
--PRINT @dsql
EXEC sp_executesql @dsql
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8dbf1/11)